# Display swagger on api route on Slim

Tags: php, swagger, slim

I just started with php and Slim framework. My main goal is to generate a RESTful API where I have a /swagger route where I show the API documentation using swagger ui.

This are the steps I followed:

- Install last version php
- Install composer
- Install required dependecies:

  - **composer require slim/slim:"4.*"**
  - **composer require zircote/swagger-php**
- Create API project (**composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton testAPI**)
- Anotate involved elements in my API
- Generate swagger file **(.\vendor\bin\openapi -output .\swagger.json .\src)**
- Add new route to my API:

**use OpenApi\Generator as OpenApiGenerator;**

```
/**
* @OA\Get(
*     path="/openapi",
*     tags={"documentation"},
*     summary="OpenAPI JSON File that describes the API",
*     @OA\Response(response="200", description="OpenAPI Description File"),
* )
*/

    $app->get('/swagger', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        $swagger = OpenApiGenerator::scan(['../swagger.json']);
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($swagger));
        return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    });};
```

But when I go and run the api and check **/swagger** route this is what I get:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": {
        "type": "SERVER_ERROR",
        "description": "WARNING: Required @OA\\PathItem() not found"
    }
}
```

Have I missed something? Or my **OpenApiGenerator::scan(['../swagger.json'])** does not make sense? I have seen people doing **OpenApiGenerator::scan(['.'])** but that gives me the exact same output.

Comment: I solved the error by using OpenApiGenerator::scan(['../src']) instead of OpenApiGenerator::scan(['../swagger.json']). Now I get the swagger json, but I would like to show it on a swaggerUI. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by making my **/swagger** route returning the swaggerUI html. For that, it is necessary to have [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) folder in the project.